# How do I render a jQuery.tmpl Template to a String?

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

The documentation for `jquery.tmpl` uses `.appendTo` to insert the template into the DOM during the rendering process:

```
$.tmpl( myTemplate, myData ).appendTo( "#target" );
```

I am attempting to convert an existing app from another templating engine, and my code needs to render a template into a string first before it is added to the DOM. Is this possible? How would that be done?

Comment: wondering why didn't jquery added a simpler way to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Templating provides `$.template()` [(see description in source code)](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/blob/master/jquery.tmpl.js#L175) - it returns array of strings after evaluating cached template with your data. I am writing from scratch (and from experiments in Chrome's console), but you'll get the whole idea.

1. Create and cache a named template function

   ```
   $("template-selector").template("template-name");
   ```
2. Get your template function and invoke it with your data

   ```
   var tmpl = $.template("template-name"); // template function
   var strings = tmpl($, {data: {<your data here>}}); // array of strings
   var output = strings.join(''); // single string
   ```

Comment: Pretty sure this wasn't true when I asked the question, so thanks for the update.

Comment: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/commits/master/jquery.tmpl.js - at the Aug 09 2010 it was renamed from `templates` to `template`, so it was true in the latest version at the time you asked your question, and it was available under `$.templates()` even earlier, actually after https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl/commit/f2eab62ad2e796f375ece518b85824edeb40c980 at May 07 2010

Answer (score 17):

The answers here didn't help me, however Adam's reply set me on the right track:
any jQuery wrapped element has a `.html()` method.

```
var output = $( "#infoWindowTemplate" ).tmpl( city_data ).html()
```

or if you need text...

```
var output = $( "#infoWindowTemplate" ).tmpl( city_data ).text()
```

but please take note, that the outermost(root) element of the template is skipped, so you should make your templates look something like this:

```html
  <script id='infoWindowTemplate' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'> 
    <div class='city_info'>
      <h1 class='title'><a href="${link}">${name}</a></h1>
      <p class='meta'>${count} offers</p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

or just use the jQuery outerHtml plugin ( http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/ ) and replace `.html()` with `.outerHTML()`

Comment: Now that we have [Handlebars](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/) for compiled Mustache templates I really don't see a compelling reason to use jQuery.tmpl

Comment: Could you give a reason why Handlebars/Mustache templates are more appropriate than jquery.tmpl? They seem very similar to me.

Comment: +1 for 'please take note, that the outermost(root) element of the template is skipped'. Saved my day.

Answer (score 13):

You could do it by just putting the result in a temporary container and taking the innerHTML of it, like this:

```
var str = $("<div />").append($.tmpl(myTemplate, myData)).html();
```

Comment: This almost worked. needs to be: var div = $("<div />"); $.tmpl(myTemplate, myData).appendTo(div); var content = div.html(); vote up for leading in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

`jQuery.tmpl` returns an HTMLElement wrapped in a jQuery object, which could be used in the same way as rendered strings were in the old template system.

```
var $template = $('#template'),
    html = $.tmpl($template, data).get();
```

I suspect that this might actually be faster than regular strings, but I don't have any profiling data for this yet.

---

**Update**

I did some basic profiling between Mustache.js and jQuery.tmpl, and the stats do not look good.

I started with 1,000 preloaded records and generated templates for them several times, averaging the results.

Mustache.js: **1783ms**
jQuery.tmpl: **2243ms**

I might wait until jQuery.tmpl closes that gap before switching.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly

```
    var s = $.tmpl(url, dataContext).get()[0].data;
```

I was wrong, above example works only if returned is somethig other that html. In case of html I use

```
    var s = $.tmpl(url, dataContext).get()[0].outerHTML
```

EDIT: After some digging I discovered diffrences between Chrome and FF (above examples works in Chrome).

Finally I found cross browser working method, lets assume that we like to build a tag. So we template will look like

```
    <a href='${url}'>${text}</a>
```

them simplest way to get resul as a string is to wrap template inside any tag and then use .html() function

```
    var t = '<div><a href='${url}'>${text}</a></div>'
    var d = {url: 'stackoverflow.com', text: 'best site'};
    var html = $.tmpl(s, d).get()[0];
    html = $(html).html();  // trick is here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare template data like this

```
var tmplData = {link:"your link",name:"yourname",count:5};
$("#idofelementwhereuwanttoappend").append($("#infoWindowTemplate").tmpl(tmpldata));
```

This `idofelementwhereuwanttoappend` is id where your template data will be rendered.

Comment: You missed the entire point of the question. I wanted to combine rendered templates together in code _before_ doing DOM operations.